# What is the use of a *.pb file in TensorFlow and how does it work?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using some implementation for creating a face recognition which uses [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5MzpY9kBtDVZ2RpVDYwWmxoSUk):

"facenet.load_model("20170512-110547/20170512-110547.pb")"

What is the use of this file? I am not sure how it works.

console log :

```
Model filename: 20170512-110547/20170512-110547.pb
distance = 0.72212267
```

Github link of the actual owner of the code
https://github.com/arunmandal53/facematch

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`pb` stands for protobuf. In TensorFlow, the protbuf file contains the graph definition as well as the weights of the model. Thus, a `pb` file is all you need to be able to run a given trained model.

Given a `pb` file, you can load it as follow.

```
def load_pb(path_to_pb):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(path_to_pb, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        return graph
```

Once you have loaded the graph, you can basically do anything. For instance, you can retrieve tensors of interest with

```
input = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
output = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
```

and use regular TensorFlow routine like:

```
sess.run(output, feed_dict={input: some_data})
```

Comment: from where i understood in layman's language it is some sort of graphics API.

Comment: It is simply a way to save to disk a model (e.g. a neural network) for later restore/reuse.

Comment: +1 for the example of how to load it. One small addition: If the pb file is not binary, I believe you need to use "google.protobuf.text_format.Merge(f.read(), graph_def)" in place of "graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())", see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/model_files

Comment: For TensorFlow v2.x this method is deprecated, but still works, if we add `.compat.v1` infixes to `gfile` and `GraphDef` names. For example, the first line becomes: `with tf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile(path_to_pb, "rb") as f`

Answer (score 27):

### Explanation

The `.pb` format is the [protocol buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) (protobuf) format, and in Tensorflow, this format is used to hold models. Protobufs are a general way to store data by Google that is much nicer to transport, as it compacts the data more efficiently and enforces a structure to the data. When used in TensorFlow, it's called a **SavedModel protocol buffer**, which is the default format when saving Keras/ Tensorflow 2.0 models. More information about this format can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md).

For example, the following code (specifically, `m.save`), will create a folder called `my_new_model`, and save in it, the `saved_model.pb`, an `assets/` folder, and a `variables/` folder.

```py
# first download a SavedModel from TFHub.dev, a website with models
m = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_130_224/classification/4")
])
m.build([None, 224, 224, 3])  # Batch input shape.
m.save("my_new_model") # defaults to save as SavedModel in tensorflow 2
```

In some places, you may also see `.h5` models, which was the default format for TF 1.X. [source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model)

---

Extra information: In TensorFlow Lite, the library for running models on mobile and IoT devices, instead of protocol buffers, flatbuffers are used. This is what the TensorFlow Lite Converter converts into (`.tflite` format). This is another Google format which is also very efficient: it allows access to any part of the message without deserialization (unlike json, xml). For devices with less memory (RAM), it makes more sense to load what you need from the model file, instead of loading the entire thing into memory to deserialize it.

---

### Loading SavedModels in TensorFlow 2

I noticed BiBi's answer to show loading models was popular, and there is a shorter way to do this in TF2:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
model_path = "/path/to/directory/inception_v1_224_quant_20181026"
model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
```

**Note,**

- the directory (i.e. `inception_v1_224_quant_20181026`) has to have a `saved_model.pb` or `saved_model.pbtxt`, otherwise the code will crash. You cannot specify the `.pb` path, specify the *directory*.
- you might get `TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable` for older models, [fix here](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_issues).

If you load a TF1 model, I found that I don't get any errors, but the loaded file doesn't behave as expected. (e.g. it doesn't have any functions on it, like predict)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [protoc](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/) to inspect the text of a .pb file:

`protoc --decode_raw < input.pb > output.txt`