# Evaluate the TensorFlow object detection model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard, evaluate

How can I evaluate my object detection model in a simple and understandable way, I used the TensorFlow's Object Detection API, but I didn’t understand the Tensorboard graphs. Can I evaluate it manually? 
Any help? :(

Comment: Please post code samples/graphs of what you're having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!
In short, yes you can. Yet it could be quite time-consuming to achieve your goal.
Here are the steps you might want to follow(assuming you have some basic understanding of Tensorflow graphs and sessions, otherwise please update your question):

1. Export your model to a frozen graph(*.pb file) via [HERE](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md). This step will give you an out-of-the-box model that you could load without any dependencies of Object Detection API.
2. Write a script to load your model(frozen graph) and perform the evaluation. Some instructions can be found from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278213/what-is-the-use-of-a-pb-file-in-tensorflow-and-how-does-it-work). Make sure you use tools such as [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) to check the input and output node names of your frozen graph.
3. Once you could perform the evaluation, you could write metrics on your own dataset, such as mAP, and loop through all images to get the desired evaluation performed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the confusion matrix to evaluate your model on the test dataset.
After training the model on your dataset, export the inference graph for evaluation.
Find the attached link which helps you step by step towards evaluation.
Best of luck!
[confusion_matrix](https://github.com/svpino/tf_object_detection_cm)