# Tensorflow Load model to check what's in it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am not very familiar w/ tensorflow, and received ".pb" file and was trying to see how they try to approach the problem.

```
model_path = os.path.join(saved_path,"model",str(k+1))
model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
print(model)
```

<tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.._UserObject object at 0x7f6d200ec748>

```
model.summary()
```

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 model.summary()

AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'

is there any way I can check the summary of the model?
Because I was wondering their job to approach the issue with segmentation task and seems like did object detection. That is why I want check what is inside the model.pb file!

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a *Keras* model so you can not check the summary. Also it won't support `compile()` and `fit()`.

Comment: I see it. Thank you @Frightera !

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51281809/14290244