# How to load an unknown tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow model called `saved_model.pb` saved in folder `my_folder` that was built in python2.7. I don't know the complete architecture of the model. Is there a way I can load it?

I have tried:

1. `model = tf.keras.models.load_model("saved_model.pb")` which gives me error: `IOError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)`.
2. `model = tf.saved_model.load(session, export_dir="my_folder", tags=None, options=None)` which gives me error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of a \*.pb file in TensorFlow and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278213/what-is-the-use-of-a-pb-file-in-tensorflow-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Trying this gives me the error `DecodeError: Error parsing message` on the line `graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())`

Comment: Hi @DanielWyatt, could you please provide the details in which tensorflow version you have saved your model and load your model. Thank You.